# javascript es6 import "expects exactly one argument"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use es6 modules but I'm hitting an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'GameObject'. import call expects
> exactly one argument.

This is in Safari 11 on macOS 10.13, by the way.

Here's my module:

```
export class GameObject {
    //code
}

export class GameLoop {
    //code
}
```

relevant html:

```
<body>
    <script type="module" src="gameFoundation.js"></script>
    <script src="gameTest.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the script that tries to use the module, which gives the aforementioned error on line 1:

```
import GameObject from "./gameFoundation.js"
import GameLoop from "./gameFoundation.js"

class Rect extends GameObject {
    //code
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript, so I imagine I'm getting something basic wildly wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `import { GameObject } from "./gameFoundation.js"`, otherwise you're trying to import default export, which is not defined here.

Comment: @wostex import { GameObject } from "./gameFoundation.js"
import { GameLoop   } from "./gameFoundation.js"
gives me an error unexpected token "{"

Comment: You cannot use `import` declarations in a normal script. Give it `type="module"` as well.

Comment: OHH, I have to use type=module on a script that imports modules? That makes sense... I guess. Add it as an answer & I'll accept

Comment: @PopKernel - I've rolled your edit to the question back (David Moles alerted me to it in a comment on my answer). Questions aren't supposed to be edited to incorporate answers, for the very reason David pointed out -- it makes the answers make no sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your exports are *named*, but you're using *default* import syntax. You need to wrap the names of what you're importing in `{...}`:

```
import { GameObject } from "./gameFoundation.js";
import { GameLoop } from "./gameFoundation.js";
```

You can also do both with one import declaration if you like:

```
import { GameObject, GameLoop } from "./gameFoundation.js";
```

Also note that `import` is only valid *in a module*, and module specifiers must be relative paths (unless you're using a bundler or an [import map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap)), so you need to change:

```
<script src="gameTest.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="module" src="./gameTest.js"></script>
```

More in [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or Chapter 13 of [my book](https://thenewtoys.dev/).

Answer (score 5):

Named exports will work for you.

Replace

```
import GameObject from "./gameFoundation.js"
import GameLoop from "./gameFoundation.js"
```

to

```
import { GameObject, GameLoop } from "./gameFoundation.js"
```

[Here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) is a good article about all ES6 *import/exports*. Will be useful to read for you.

Answer (score 2):

In es6 to make imports like this:

```
import GameObject from "./gameFoundation.js"
```

your export should look like this:

```
export default class GameObject { }
```

in your case you need to make your imports like this:

```
import { GameObject, GameLoop } from './gameFoundation.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using ES6 syntax which needs to be transpiled into native plain old javascript syntax to get loaded into the browser.

Please, refer to the following link:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them

It will guide you about transpiler that may solve your problem.