# Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected identifier 'invariant'. import call expects exactly one argument. no stack

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

So Xcode got updated to the 13.2.1 version and since that update I am no being able to run the app. It builds successfully but doesn't run, this error shows up:

I tried recloning the app but it doesn't work, also I build and run another react native app and it works normally and also download the simulators for iOS 15 because the update brings the 15.2 which is the latest iOS version.

Please help.

[image]

```
React Native info:

    System:
    OS: macOS 12.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Memory: 190.46 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.1/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2021.11.15.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 28, 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 32.0.0
      System Images: android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034
    Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.8 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this isn't about the upgrade but your definition of components. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140375/javascript-es6-import-expects-exactly-one-argument) may help you.